# Recursively search for images in local TDS tree

Tags: recursion, directory, search

Latex finds `~/texmf/generic/images/f.ps` but not `~/texmf/generic/images/d/f.ps`

Is there a way to make it recursively search folders in my local texmf tree?

Comment: by default search is recursive

Comment: Thank you, but as I've mentioned it doesn't find files in sub-directories.
I'm on Debian Linux. What might cause it not to search recursively?.

Thanks